# Create SignalR server to use across multiple applications

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, microservices

I am building a micro-service-oriented .NET Core web application and now I want to add real-time communication. It is possible to create a SignalR server and publish it on Azure? I want to use it in my microservices to send messages to users when a certain even occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy your app to Azure and point your users to your hub endpoint with no problems. You have two options here:

- Use `SignalR` and manually manage the connections and other signalR stuff if you will scale your application. For example, when you have 2 web apps and the client connects to one of them, you need to "tell" to other app that you have a new client connected using for example Redis Blackplane.
- Use `Azure SignalR` and this kind of management is not needed, what you need to provide is only 1 app with the hub logic. So when a client connects to your hub it is automaticaly redirected to the `Azure SignalR`.

You can read more about this two options here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-scale-aspnet-core

> Why not deploy SignalR myself?´
>
> It is still a valid approach to deploy your own Azure web app supporting ASP.NET Core SignalR as a backend component to your overall web application.
> One of the key reasons to use the Azure SignalR Service is simplicity. With Azure SignalR Service, you don't need to handle problems like performance, scalability, availability. These issues are handled for you with a 99.9% service-level agreement.
> Also, WebSockets are typically the preferred technique to support real-time content updates. However, load balancing a large number of persistent WebSocket connections becomes a complicated problem to solve as you scale. Common solutions leverage: DNS load balancing, hardware load balancers, and software load balancing. Azure SignalR Service handles this problem for you.
> Another reason may be you have no requirements to actually host a web application at all. The logic of your web application may leverage Serverless computing. For example, maybe your code is only hosted and executed on demand with Azure Functions triggers. This scenario can be tricky because your code only runs on-demand and doesn't maintain long connections with clients. Azure SignalR Service can handle this situation since the service already manages connections for you. See the overview on how to use SignalR Service with Azure Functions for more details.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot! One more question: I have to create a hub and implement methods in every micro-service? Or I can create something like a HubService and inject it where I need it?

Comment: You can inject your hub when mapping SignalR like ```app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<YourHubService>("/someRoute");
            });``` This is valid for both ```SignalR``` and ```Azure SignalR```.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Azure SignalR Service (my Azure subscription doesn't have the permission) so I have to deploy my own SignalR web app. I've been searching for over 2 hours how to create and deploy a SignalR web app and than connect to it from my microservice but I didn't find anything helpful. Everyone seems to integrate SignalR directly in the project, but I don't want to do this for every microservice I have. Is there any workaround?

Comment: First you create your signalR app and deploy to azure. Then you can create a library that will connect to your SingalR app and import it in every project you need.

Comment: And how I connect to SignalR app?

Comment: You can use c# library's or javascript library's to do that. You have the documentation from Microsoft for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, this is the official quick start sample.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core